# Context issue when using Anko DSL within customized adapter for ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, kotlin, anko

I am trying to write a general-purpose adapter for `ListView` which allows using Anko DSL as the content of items. The code is listed below. As you can see, there is an ugly patch `with(viewGroup!!.context)` to make the code work. It doesn't like other Anko example you have see. If I remove the `with` statement, my app will crash by

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

Is there any way to avoid the `with` statement?

```
import java.util.*
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter

class AnkoAdapter(itemFactory: () -> AbstractList<Any>, viewFactory: (index: Int, items: AbstractList<Any>, view: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?) -> View): BaseAdapter() {
    val viewFactory = viewFactory
    val items: AbstractList<Any> by lazy { itemFactory() }

    override fun getView(index: Int, view: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?): View {
        return viewFactory(index, items, view, viewGroup)
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun getItem(index: Int): Any {
        return items.get(index)
    }

    override fun getItemId(index: Int): Long {
        return items.get(index).hashCode().toLong() + (index.toLong() * Int.MAX_VALUE)
    }
}

// -------------
// In main acitivty.
...
val items = listOf<String>("Mary", "Lisa", "Cheryl", "Linda")
val buttonCaption = "..."
listView.adapter = AnkoAdapter({items as AbstractList<Any>}) {
    index: Int, items: AbstractList<Any>, view: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup? ->
    with(viewGroup!!.context) {
        linearLayout {
            textView(items[index].toString())
            button(buttonCaption)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A2LukgT2mKc), here is the modified version:

```
class AnkoAdapter<T>(itemFactory: () -> List<T>, viewFactory: Context.(index: Int, items: List<T>, view: View?) -> View): BaseAdapter() {
    val viewFactory = viewFactory
    val items: List<T> by lazy { itemFactory() }

    override fun getView(index: Int, view: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?): View {
        return viewGroup!!.context.viewFactory(index, items, view)
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun getItem(index: Int): T {
        return items.get(index)
    }

    override fun getItemId(index: Int): Long {

        return (items.get(index) as Any).hashCode().toLong() + (index.toLong() * Int.MAX_VALUE)
    }
}

val items = listOf<String>("Mary", "Lisa", "Cheryl", "Linda")
val buttonCaption = "..."
lockView.adapter = AnkoAdapter<String>({ items }) {
    index, items, view ->
    linearLayout {
        textView(items[index])
        button(buttonCaption)
    }
}
```